# JSOUP connection not working for specific websites?

Tags: jsoup

I´m trying to connect to a website and request the HTML document.

```
public void anyAction() {
        new HttpThread().start();
}
```

```
class HttpThread extends Thread {
        public void run() {
            try {
                String url = "https://example.com/something"
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url)
                                    .timeout(30000)
                                    .get();
                // rest of the code
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                // print e.toString()
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
}
```

but `doc` remains empty and the rest of the code won´t be executed. Also, I´m not getting any error message despite catching errors with `HttpStatusException`.

I found a lot of threads with similar problems but none of the suggestions worked for me. I also tried:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url)
                        .ignoreContentType(true)
                        .referrer("http://www.google.com")
                        .maxBodySize(Integer.MAX_VALUE)
                        .header("Accept-Encoding", "gzip")
                        .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0")   //tried many different agents
                        .timeout(Integer.MAX_VALUE)
                        .followRedirects(true)
                        .get();   //also tried .post()
```

This is the HTML-code of the website, which includes a bit of javascript:

```
<html><head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>This is the title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">        
        <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery-1.2.min.js"></script>    
        <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>


    </head>

    <body>
        <table class="header">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td>
                    <div id="attr1" class="attr1"><div class="test">something</div></div>
                </td>
            </tr>   
        </tbody></table>
        <div id="attr2" class="attr2" style="visibility: hidden;">something</div>
        <div id="attr3" class="attr3" style="visibility: hidden;">something</div>
        <div id="attr4" class="attr4" style="visibility: hidden;">something</div>
        <div id="attr5" class="attr5" style="visibility: hidden;">something</div>
        <div id="attr6" class="attr6" style="visibility: hidden;">something</div>
        <div id="attr7" class="info">something</div>
        <div id="attr8" class="attr8" style="visibility: visible;">something</div>

        <script language="javascript">

            function getParam ( strParamName ) {
                strParams = document.location.search.substring ( 1 , document.location.search.length );
                varParams = strParams.split ( '&' );
                for (var intPos = 0; intPos < varParams.length; ++intPos ) {
                    varParam = varParams[intPos].split ( '=' );
                    if ( varParam[0] == strParamName ) {
                        return varParam[1];
                    }
                }
            }


            function loadData (url) {
                var mydata = null;
                $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    async: false,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (json) {
                        mydata = json;                  ;
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        mydata = null;
                    }
                });

                return mydata;  
            }

            function initialize () {                

                display = new Object();             
                refreshRoomInfos();                         
                insertData();
                timer = window.setInterval ( "insertData()" , 30000 );
                timer = window.setInterval ( "refreshRoomInfos()" , 60000 );

            }

            function refreshRoomInfos() {

                var displayId = getParam('displayId');
                var virtualNowDate = getParam('virtualNowDate');
                var preview = getParam('preview');
                var roomRestUrl;

                if (typeof displayId === "undefined" || displayId === "") {                 
                    roomRestUrl = '../rest/displayService/get/rooms?roomId=' + getParam('roomId');
                } else {
                    roomRestUrl = '../rest/displayService/get/rooms?displayId=' + displayId;                    
                }

                roomData = loadData(roomRestUrl);
                if (typeof roomData !== "undefined" && roomData != null) {
                    var room = roomData[0]; 

                    if (typeof room !== "undefined" && room != null) {
                        var attr1 =  room.displayName;              
                        if (typeof attr1 === "undefined" || attr1 === "") {                     
                            attr1 = room.name;                                      
                        }
                        display.roomId = room.id;        
                        fillHTML('room', "<div class=\"test\">" + attr1 + "</div>");

                        if (typeof room.additionalDisplayText !== "undefined" && room.additionalDisplayText != null) {
                            fillHTML('attr7', room.additionalDisplayText);
                        }    
                    }
                }
            }

            function insertData() {
                if (typeof display.roomId !== "undefined") {

                        + "&virtualNowDate=" + virtualNowDate
                        + "&preview=" + preview

                    var apptURL = '../rest/displayService/get/appointments/' + display.roomId + '/50?displayFlag=false';
                    var virtualNowDate = getParam('virtualNowDate');
                    if(virtualNowDate){
                        apptURL += "&virtualNowDate=" + virtualNowDate;
                    }
                    var preview = getParam('preview');
                    if(preview){
                        apptURL += "&preview=" + preview;
                    }
                    var appointments = loadData(apptURL);
                    var appointment = getCurrentAppointment(appointments);              
                    if (appointment != null)  {

                        setVisibleHTML('attr2', 'visible');
                        setVisibleHTML('attr5', 'visible');
                        setVisibleHTML('attr6', 'visible');
                        setVisibleHTML('attr3', 'visible');
                        setVisibleHTML('attr4', 'visible');
                        setVisibleHTML('attr8', 'hidden');

                        var belosEvent = appointment.event;

                        // Titel des Appointments
                        var title = appointment.displayTitle;
                        if (typeof title === "undefined"
                                || title === "") {
                            title = belosEvent.attr4;

                            if (typeof appointment.subattr4 !== "undefined" && appointment.subattr4 !== ""
                                    && appointment.subattr4 !== title) {
                                title += " - " + appointment.subattr4;
                            }
                        }

                        // Startdatum des Appointments
                        var dateFrom = moment(appointment.startDate).toDate();
                        var dateFromString =
                                dateFrom.getHours()
                                + ":"
                                + (dateFrom.getMinutes().toString().length === 1 ? "0" + dateFrom.getMinutes() : dateFrom.getMinutes());
                        // Enddatum des Appointments
                        var dateTo = moment(appointment.endDate).toDate();
                        //    dateTo.setTime(appointment.endDate);
                        var dateToString =
                                dateTo.getHours()
                                + ":"
                                + (dateTo.getMinutes().toString().length === 1 ? "0" + dateTo.getMinutes() : dateTo.getMinutes());
                        //falls mehrtägiger Termin
                        if(!(dateFrom.getDate()===dateTo.getDate()&&dateFrom.getMonth()===dateTo.getMonth()&&dateFrom.getFullYear()===dateTo.getFullYear())){
                            //falls Date-Parameter über URL übergeben wurde
                            if(paramD!==null&&paramD!==undefined){
                                //falls heute nicht zwischen Terminbeginn und Terminende oder nicht der der letzte Tag des mehrtägigen Termins ist
                                if(!((!(now.getDate()===dateFrom.getDate()&&now.getMonth()===now.getMonth()&&now.getFullYear()===dateFrom.getFullYear())&&
                                        !(now.getDate()===dateTo.getDate()&&now.getMonth()===dateTo.getMonth()&&now.getFullYear()===dateTo.getFullYear)&&
                                        dateFrom.getTime()<now.getTime()&&now.getTime()<dateTo.getTime())||
                                        now.getDate()===dateTo.getDate()&&now.getMonth()===dateTo.getMonth()&&now.getFullYear()===dateTo.getFullYear())){
                                    now = paramD;
                                }
                            }
                            //falls heute erster Tag, dann behalte Startuhrzeit bei, ansonsten setze sie auf 00:00
                            dateFromString = dateFrom.getDate()===now.getDate()&&dateFrom.getMonth()===now.getMonth()&&dateFrom.getFullYear()===now.getFullYear() ? dateFromString : "00:00";
                            //falls heute letzter Tag, dann behalte Enduhrzeit bei, ansonsten setze sie auf 23:59
                            dateToString = dateTo.getDate()===now.getDate()&&dateTo.getMonth()===now.getMonth()&&dateTo.getFullYear()===now.getFullYear() ? dateToString : "23:59";
                        }

                        // Organisator des Appointments
                        var attr6 = belosEvent.attr6.lastname;
                        if (typeof belosEvent.attr6.firstname !== "undefined"
                                && belosEvent.attr6.firstname !== "") {
                            attr6 += ", " + belosEvent.attr6.firstname;
                        }
                        if (belosEvent.attr6.lastname === "System"
                                && belosEvent.attr6.firstname === "System") {
                            attr6 = null;
                        }

                        fillHTML('attr2', dateFromString + " - " + dateToString + " Uhr");

                        fillHTML('attr6', attr6);
                        fillHTML('attr4', title);

                    } else {
                        setVisibleHTML('attr2', 'hidden');
                        setVisibleHTML('attr5', 'hidden');
                        setVisibleHTML('attr6', 'hidden');
                        setVisibleHTML('attr3', 'hidden');
                        setVisibleHTML('attr4', 'hidden');
                        setVisibleHTML('attr8', 'visible');

                    }   
                }               
            }

            function setVisibleHTML(fieldId, visible) {
                //alert(fieldId);
                var elem = document.getElementById(fieldId);                
                elem.style.visibility = visible;
            }

            function fillHTML(fieldId, value) {             
                var elem = document.getElementById(fieldId);                
                elem.innerHTML = value;
            }

            function getCurrentAppointment(appointments) {
                var appointment = null;
                var now = new Date();   
                var virtualNowDate = getParam('virtualNowDate');
                if(virtualNowDate){
                    now = virtualNowDate;
                }
                console.log("virtualNowDate " + virtualNowDate);
                console.log("NOW " + now);
                if (appointments != null && appointments.length > 0) {
                    console.log("appointments not null and length > 0 ");
                    for (var i = 0; i < appointments.length; i++) {
                        appointment =  appointments[i];                     
                        if (appointment != null && now <= moment(appointment.endDateWaiting).toDate()) {
                            return appointment;
                        }
                        appointment = null;
                    }                               
                }
                return appointment;
            }

            initialize();

        </script>




</body></html>
```

Comment: If your code works on some sites and does not work on others, then the problem is the website. Some sites require some extra info, which you probably don't supply. If you'll give one or two examples of non working sites, someone will be able to help.

Comment: It works on other sites, but not on that specific site. I can´t give you the link because it´s not accessible without the right VPN. The site is accessible for me and calling it via web-browser does not require a authentication. Also, I can´t imagine that the site would need any cookies, So, which extra info could there be, that is missing?

Comment: Open your browser's dev tools. load that site and watch the requests from the browser. Maybe that will give a hint.

Answer (score 0):

For Network operations,it's better to include it in a `Thread` or in `AsyncTask` or if u are using Kotlin,use `Coroutines`.
Try the following:

```
Thread(Runnable{

try{
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url)
                        .ignoreContentType(true)
                        .referrer("http://www.google.com")
                        .maxBodySize(Integer.MAX_VALUE)
                        .header("Accept-Encoding", "gzip")
                        .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0")   //tried many different agents
                        .timeout(Integer.MAX_VALUE)
                        .followRedirects(true)
                        .get();   //also tried .post()

}catch(e: IOException){
 e.printStackTrace()

}


})
```

`Note:`According for what you need from your code,you will choose the right method for you,if you don't care about using return result to use it outside a thread,so `thread(multithreading)` is your right choice,but if you care about return result to use it elsewhere,use `coroutines`.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the URL from https to http solved my problem... >.<

Now a new problem regarding the script on the site popped up, but I´ll post a new question for that since the main issue is solved.